# How can I create a JSON (jQuery), post an whole array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to create an event handler (jQuery) that will pick all elements of specific class, each unique ID value, post json array, loop through php, finally update view.

I have no problem with selecting one instance.

**Mostly looking how to create the array of id,value to pass for processing.

Thank You

Comment: You need to give more information. I don't understand what you are trying to do. What have you tried? Is there a specific part of it that you don't know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (As a strting point):

```
$('.class').each(function(){
 // do somthing with $(this)
});
```

Of course, if you post some more details, I can expand on this.

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of all selected elements

```
var elArray = $('.classToSelect').get();
```

After this you may use

```
$.each(elArray, function(el){
     var id = el.id;
     var value = el.value;
     //code goes here
}
```

A small plugin script from http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ is perfect for JSON encoding and decoding:

```
var postdata = $.toJSON(elArray);
```

generates a well formatted JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will give you an array of the ids of the elements with class myclass:

```
var id_array = $.map($(".myclass"),function(el){return el.id;});
```

You can then send the array to your server as JSON, or as a comma separated string, or any other way you want.